# Proving $f$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
3^k,  & \text{if $2^{k-1}<||(x,y)||\le2^k$} \\
0, & \text{if (x,y) = (0,0) }
\end{cases}$

Prove $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

I've tried proving that partial derivatives are defined with no success, and I don't see how do I use the definition of differentiability here.

Thanks

Comment: Existence of partial derivatives is not enough to deduce differentiability, unless at least one of them is continuous at the required point. And what is that $\;k\;$ there? Natural or integer?

Comment: k is an integer

Answer (score 0):

From symmetry , you can tell that if $f$ is differentiable then the gradient is $(0,0)$

So you need to prove that $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)}{||h||} =0 $$

which is given by $$\frac{3^k}{2^{k-1}} > \frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} \geq \frac{3^k}{2^k} $$
$$||(x,y)||\to 0 \iff k\to -\infty$$

$$\implies \lim_{||(x,y)|| \to 0} \frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} = 0,$$

So $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: There is no open neighbourhood of (0,0) where $f$ is continuous

Comment: i don't understand how did you get this inequality... maybe i should of mentioned that k is not constant.

Comment: @Dan sorry I made a mistake earlier but I edited my answer and now it is ok

Comment: thanks for your help. however, I haven't learned yet about gradients. could you please explain more why this proves it? can this be proven in another way?

Comment: @Dan so what is exactly your definition of differentiability ?

Comment: @Dan , if $f$ is differentiable in $a$ then the gradient of $f$ in $a$ is the vector $v$ such that $f(a+h)=f(a)+(v|h)+o(||h||)$

Comment: f is differentiable at (x,y) if there are $A$, $B$ such that $f(x+\Delta x,y+ \Delta y) = f(x,y) +A \Delta x +B \Delta y + o(||\Delta x, \Delta y||)$   where  $(\Delta x, \Delta y) \to (0,0)$

Comment: so I i've been thinking to prove that $f(\Delta x,\Delta y) = o(||\Delta x, \Delta y||)$    $(\Delta x, \Delta y) \to (0,0)$. That means $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} = 0$

Comment: @Dan here $(A,B)$ is the gradient. $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and what I call $h$ is your $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ so yes you need to prove that $f(\Delta x,\Delta y)=o(||\Delta x, \Delta y||)$ and this is what I have done in my answer